# Increase arrow thickness in ternary plot [ggtern]

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtern

Here's some example code.

```
library(ggtern)
# Based of random data.
DATA <- data.frame(A = runif(100), B = runif(100), C = runif(100))
plot <- ggtern(data = DATA, 
               mapping = aes(x = A, y = B, z = C)) + 
        geom_point() + ggtern::theme_bw(base_size = 30) + theme_arrowlarge()
plot
```

[image]

How do I increase the thickness of the arrows and the arrowheads? They are just way too thin once I start increasing the size of labels.

Also, how do I use the parameter base_size with the ggtern themes? Because it seems it only works with certain themes, I am not sure if I am using this correctly if I want to scale everything up, including the arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the line thickness of the arrows, you can access `tern.axis.arrow` through the `theme()` function. Then change the size of `element_line()` to be whatever you'd prefer.

```
library(ggtern)
# Based of random data.
DATA <- data.frame(A = runif(100), B = runif(100), C = runif(100))
ggtern(data = DATA, 
               mapping = aes(x = A, y = B, z = C)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  ggtern::theme_bw(base_size = 30) + 
  theme_arrowlarge() +
  theme(tern.axis.arrow = element_line(size = 3))
```

If you'd like to modify the arrow options directly, you can see from the code behind the `ggtern::theme_bw` function that the lineend calls from a global option called `tern.arrow`.

```
function (base_size = 12, base_family = "") 
{
    base = ggplot2::theme_bw(base_size, base_family)
    theme_ggtern(base_size, base_family) %+replace% base %+replace% 
        theme(tern.plot.background = element_rect(size = NA, 
            color = NA), tern.axis.line = element_line(color = base$panel.border$colour), 
            tern.axis.arrow = element_line(color = base$panel.border$colour, 
                lineend = getOption("tern.arrow")))
}
<bytecode: 0x7fb23868a558>
<environment: namespace:ggtern>
```

So, you can play around with the options for the arrow as needed to adjust the arrow type, size, etc. For example, here we change the arrow head to be 0.75 cm and the line thickness to be size 3.

```
DATA <- data.frame(A = runif(100), B = runif(100), C = runif(100))
options(tern.arrow = arrow(type = "open", length = unit(.75, "cm")))
ggtern(data = DATA, 
               mapping = aes(x = A, y = B, z = C)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  ggtern::theme_bw(base_size = 30) + 
  theme_arrowlarge() +
  theme(tern.axis.arrow = element_line(size = 3))
```

This produces [a figure with thicker lines and bigger arrows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W06Rw.png).

Comment: Thank you! That works but just a note of caution, it seems to be working only with ggtern::theme_bw, because I have tried with theme_grey() and I get Error in validDetails.segments(x): invalid 'arrow' argument